# Node.js screenshotting HTML elements

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Recently I was asked to make a Discord bot to grab player coin values from http://www.futbin.com/

Once finished I was asked if I could also include the card picture: http://www.futbin.com/17/player/15230/Hazard

Examining the card I found it's not just one image it's actually built from pieces all put together making it more difficult so I looked into creating a screenshot from specific elements.

Phantomjs was said to do this so I started writing some code to test this:

```
var page = new WebPage(); 
    page.open('http://www.futbin.com/17/player/15230/Hazard', function (status) {
    console.log("Loaded");
    page.render('image.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

My console.log took approximately 15-20 seconds to run which is terrible. My Node.js http.request takes less than a second to grab the entire webpage.

The second problem is Phantomjs doesn't like the discord.io library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.io) and throws errors when run using phantomjs.exe.

My big question, what is the best way to get an image of this card using Node.js preferably without something like Phantomjs if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a more complete browser engine in order to render the page correctly, and Selenium running Chrome works very well for this.

For a quick way to get a Selenium+Chrome server running, there's a handy Docker image available which you can use to start a new container like so:

`docker run -l scraper -d -p 127.0.0.1:4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome:latest`

Once that's up and running, you can use the WebDriverIO node package (`npm install webdriverio`) to communicate with it with a script such as:

```
let WebDriverIO = require('webdriverio');

let browser = WebDriverIO.remote({
  baseUrl: 'http://www.futbin.com',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 4444,
  waitforTimeout: 10 * 1000,
  logLevel: 'silent',
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
  }
});

browser
  .init()
  .url('/17/player/15230/Hazard')
  .saveScreenshot('/path/to/screenshot.png');
```

Once you've run that script, you should end up with a screenshot in the directory specified (i.e. `/path/to/screenshot.png`). See API docs for a full list of features - http://webdriver.io/api.html

And finally to stop the Docker container (I'm just using labels here to quickly identify the container):

```
docker stop `docker ps --filter label=scraper -q`
```

This doesn't help with extracting just the specific portion of the page you need, but perhaps you can thereafter push the image through an image slicer of some kind (imagemagick?).